# Starting batch with a particular goto command

Tags: batch-file, goto, process.start

I want to know if it is possible to start a batch thin in a particular goto function from another batch?

thus not just starting another batch file but also have the "mother" batch select a particular goto option with in the "child"batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.bat`

```
call 2.bat /c goto :this
call 2.bat /c call :that
```

.

`2.bat`

```
if "%1"=="/c" shift & shift & %2 %3
goto :eof

:this
echo This!
goto :eof

:that
echo That!
goto :eof
```

**EDIT:** My original post was closest to correct. But I've corrected my mistake(s).

I double shift to remove %1 and %2 to the left, bringing any other variables passed to the %1 and %2 positions. I then execute %2 and %3 because the effect of the shifts won't take effect until the line is finished being executed / interpreted.

Comment: Why do you shift two times without any effect?

Comment: @jeb - Oops, my mistake. Must have been more tired than I thought.

Comment: Nice idea, but again it doesn't work :-) As the shift has no effect to the `%1 %2` in the same line

Comment: @jeb - Sigh, I'll get it right yet. I guess I need to pay attention when I tell others they need to test code before they post it. 8\

Answer (score 1):

Just have the parent/mother batch file and pass a parameter to the child batch file.

**mom.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Here we go
CALL child.bat 3
PAUSE
```

**child.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF

IF "%1"=="1" Goto 1
IF "%1"=="2" Goto 2 
IF "%1"=="3" Goto 3

EXIT

:1

 ECHO 1!
 PAUSE
 EXIT

:2

 ECHO 2!
 PAUSE
 EXIT

:3

 ECHO 3!
 PAUSE
 EXIT
```

This example should echo **3!** as the mother batch file passes the parameter **3** to the child batch file.

Comment: +1, Why you are checking `%1`? Just jump to it should also work

Comment: @jeb - I guess it depends on how you are naming the Goto parameters, and if you can modify the child batch file or not, but good point.

Comment: I cant seam to get either of the sugestions to work. and is the call function ideal cause im trying to the Mom bat to call its self with %0 and open up the goto function in the new window. this way i can keep diffrent functions open and continue navigating in the original

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables sorry your bat dose work just not how I want. I have a bat with difrent functions and i want to expand some of them into a new window so i can see multiple functions simutainiously on my screen otherwise im hopping inbetween functions ussing the one window. dose this make sense?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `start C:\CHILD.bat FUNCTION_X_INSIDE_CHILD_BAT_NOT_MOTHER_BAT`?  Why are you passing `GOTO` in your parameter?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables i think its quite clear that i have gotten lost in my own programing lol it can be start C:\CHILD.bat FUNCTION_X_INSIDE_CHILD_BAT_NOT_MOTHER_BAT? but i then realised that this would call another bat I want to have the bat open its self and then zip to the goto command orriginaly called for. my appologies for the dificult explaination

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's a hack.

Normally you would do this with a bit of help from the called batch file.

**main.bat**

```
call second.bat :theFunction
```

**second.bat*

```
goto %1

...
:theFunction
```

The hack uses a feature-bug, you only need the same label as in the second.bat.
And it only works if you start the second.bat without `call`

**main.bat**

```
call :theFunction
echo back in main
exit /b

:theFunction
second.bat 
echo back in the func in main, this line will never reached
exit /b This line will also never reached
```

When the second.bat returns , it will return to the line after the `call` in main.bat

Answer (score 0):

In the batch file that you are calling put this at the top

```
if not %1=="" goto :%1
```

In the batch file you are using to call it put

```
call b.bat labelname
```

Obviously this is limited depending on what you are trying to do but the basic functionality works.